# Pass Selection Option to New Page

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, cookiestore

I've got a requirement to pass the currently selected option from an ng-option dropdown on one page and make it the default selection of the ng-option dropdown on another page.

I can save the selected option to $cookieStore and pass it to the next page. But I can't make it the preselected default option on the new page dropdown.

On Controller 1, I have:

```
$scope.selectType = [
{ name: 'a' },
{ name: 'b' },
{ name: 'c' },
{ name: 'd' } ] 
$scope.preSelectTypes = $scope.selectType[0]
```

This populates the initial dropdown and makes 'a' the default option.

I also have the code below, which saves the selected option to $cookieStore:

```
$cookieStore.put('abe', $scope.preSelectTypes)
```

On Controller 2, I have the below code which gets the $cookieStore value:

```
$scope.selectType = $cookieStore.get('abe')
```

$scope.selectType.name returns the previously selected option name. But I can't figure out how to match it to the new dropdown and make it the default selection on the dropdown.

And ng-option doesn't seem to allow you to pull the value Angular assigns to each option to use on another controller, so I can't match by that.

Comment: Can you write your <select> so that we can check what is really not working. If possible add a fiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a factory that is used to populate select.  Then use a watch to monitor the value of the select and when it changes update the factory. Then use the selectFactory value to set the value in the controller for you second view.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('myController', function($scope, selectFactory) {
  $scope.selectModel = selectFactory.selectValue;

  $scope.$watch($scope.selectModel, function() {
    selectFactory.selectValue = $scope.selectModel;
  });
});

angular.module('myapp').controller('mySecondController', function($scope, selectFactory) {
  $scope.selectModel = selectFactory.selectModel;
});

angular.module('myapp').factory('selectFactory', function() {
return {
  selectValue: null
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using ng-model on the select element in the second page, in which case you can use the following code:

```
$scope.ngModelProperty = $scope.selectType
```

If you need the ng-model and selectType variables to be in different scopes, it's a little more complicated but the $scope service can easily manage it. You generally want to have ng-model point to a predefined value anyway, otherwise your select starts with an ugly empty option in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had already tried data-ng-model='selectType' on the dropdown on the second page, but it doesn't work. I still get <option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>

Comment: I would bet that it's because ng-model is a very finnicky directive; it should always have a dot in it. This page explains why: http://learnwebtutorials.com/why-ng-model-value-should-contain-a-dot.